# symfony2.1 translatable saved, but not retrieved

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

Basically, I had the same problem as here:

[Symfony2 & Translatable : entity's locale is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532667/symfony2-translatable-entitys-locale-is-empty)

Translations where saved in the `ext_translations` table, but where not being displayed.

After adding the proposed fix, it DID work.

Today I upgraded from 2.0 to 2.1   I managed to get pretty much everything working so far.

But now my translatables are again not being displayed properly (they ARE still being saved properly).

I think it has something to do with the changes to where and how the users locale is stored in 2.1 compared to 2.0 .. but i cannot figure this one out.

Comment: since apearently i cant answer my own question

Comment: i have the solution,  but i cant post it   :( ..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by registering a custom listener

```
namespace XXX;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
   private $defaultLocale;

   public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
   {
       $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
   }

   public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
   {
       $request = $event->getRequest();
       if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
           return;
       }

       if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
           $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $request->getLocale());
       } else {
           $request->setDefaultLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale',             $this->defaultLocale));
       }
   }

   static public function getSubscribedEvents()
   {
       return array(
           // must be registered before the default Locale listener
           KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
       );
   }
}
```

then changed

```
$request->setDefaultLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
```

to

```
$request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale'));
```

and used

```
$this->getRequest()->getSession()->set('_locale', 'nl');
```

to set the locale, translations and translatables now work

hope this also helps someone else ..